# Fill created form components from another form in C#

Tags: c#, forms

i create a new form using the code below.

```
private void CNPictureBox2_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RefImgForm RefImgForm = new RefImgForm();
    RefImgForm.MainFrm = this;
    RefImgForm.Show();
}
```

I want to send data from the form that i create second form. The problem is that i cannot send data to the new form when creating it. I want to send data when i take some data from user and then send this data by button click event. How can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a new method in second form

```
public void ReceiveData(....)
{
...
}
```

and call this from first form on button click

```
private RefImgForm frm2 = null;
private void CNPictureBox2_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    frm2 = new RefImgForm();
    frm2.MainFrm = this;
    frm2.Show();
}
private void Button_Click(...)
{
    if (frm2 != null)
        frm2.ReceiveData(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a delegate in the parent form like this:

```
      delegate void SendData(object data);
      SendData sendDataobj;
```

make a method in the child form like `ProcessData` and use the following code:

```
private void CNPictureBox2_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    RefImgForm RefImgForm = new RefImgForm();
    RefImgForm.MainFrm = this;
    sendDataobj = new SendData(RefImgForm.ProcessData)
    RefImgForm.Show();
}
```

for calling the delegate you can use:

```
    sendDataobj(data);
    sendDataobj.Invoke(data);
```

both are synchronous calls.

if you want to call it asynchronously you can use:

```
sendDataobj.BeginInvoke
```